# Spy on the electron.BrowserWindow constructor and return a mock object with jasmine

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, electron

I have seen that there are some other posts on this site concerning how to spy on constructors. I understood that I should overwrite the constructor in the prototype of the external library. Which would be like spying on a function from an external library, e.g.:

```
import * as cp from 'child_process';

spyOn(cp, 'spawn').and.returnValue(...);
```

However in my concrete case I seem to not be able to map this answer to my problem, since there doesn't seem to be a `constructor` or `init` method in the prototype of the type I want to mock.

I am using jasmine to do some unit tests on an Electron app. Imagine the method to test contains the following code:

```
public methodToTest() {
  this.firstWindow = new BrowserWindow(...);
  // hide is called, or for that matter any other method that I want to spy upon
  this.firstWindow.hide();
}
```

In the test I want to check whether a specific method on the `BrowserWindow` has been called (`hide` in this example).

I setup the test in the following way:

```
import * as electron from 'electron';

// ...

beforeEach(() => {

    browserWindowSpy = createSpyObj('browser', [ 'on', 'hide', 'show']);

    // there is no constructor or init method on the prototype
    spyOn(electron.BrowserWindow.prototype, 'constructor').and.returnValue(browserWindowSpy);

    underTest = new Application();
});
```

There is a constructor in the `electron.d.ts` file if I look through the type definition, but I have no clue how to reference it.

Having a reference to `browserWindowSpy` I could then use this inside the tests to test some expectations. What would be a way to mock in situations like that, where a type comes from an external library and is not a function but has to be instantiated with the `new` keyword. I was struggling with this scenario or quite some time now.

PS: I do have a workaround but I think it is quite ugly and would want a better suggestion :) I use a creator method for the `BrowserWindow` inside the class and spy on that to return the fake browser (you should not mock methods of the class under test):

```
protected createBrowserWindow(options?: any): BrowserWindow{
  return new BrowserWindow(options);
}

public methodToTest() {
  this.firstWindow = this.createBrowserWindow(...);
  // hide is called, or for that matter any other method that I want to spy upon
  this.firstWindow.hide();
}
```

and in the test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    browserWindowSpy = createSpyObj('browser', [ 'on', 'hide', 'show']);
    underTest = new Application();
    spyOn(underTest, 'createBrowserWindow').and.returnValue(browserWindowSpy);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mockery`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockery) to mock objects in Node.

```
import * as mockery from "mockery";
```

Then, to create a fake `BrowserWindow` object, you can do this in your `beforeEach`:

```
const fakeBrowserWindow = jasmine.createSpyObj("browser", ["hide"]);
const fakeBrowserWindowCtr = jasmine.createSpy("BWCtr").and.returnValue(fakeBrowserWindow);

mockery.enable();
mockery.registerMock("electron", { BrowserWindow: fakeBrowserWindowCtr });
```

In your `afterEach` do:

```
mockery.deregisterAll();
mockery.disable();
```

Then, whenever your code requires electron like so:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
```

It will return the fake `BrowserWindow`.

One caveat of this is that if you load the script that you're testing before the mocks are set up, you'll use the original object, not the mock.

So either delay importing the script until you've called `mockery.registerMock`, or do your `electron` requires at the function level, not the module level.